# How to de-structure/match json type in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

In order to return a default `json` in case of an error, I've written the following function where I'm trying to use a match statement against a `json|error` type in ballerina 0.991.0

This:

```
function jsonIt(json|error myJson)returns json{
    match myJson {
        var error(detail,message) => return {};            
        _ => return {};
    }
}
```

Compiles (ignore the swallowed error for the sake of argument), but obviously doesn't return the json value.

This:

```
function jsonIt(json|error myJson)returns json{
    match myJson {
        json j  => return j;
        var error(detail,reason) => return {};
    }
}
```

Won't compile => `extraneous input 'json'`

Basically, I can't find any way to match against the possible `json` type. I've tried:

`json mj=> return mj;`

`var mj => return mj; //doesn't limit type to json`

and a few others. Basically, I can't find a way to match the json type, or destructure it similar to `error(d,m)`

While this questions stands on its own, suggesting a more idiomatic way to accomplish this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your problem description, I think you are trying to do a type switch here. i.e., checking whether a value belongs to a particular type. You can use [type test expression](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/type-test-expression.html) in Ballerina for this use case. Following two approaches should work.

```
function jsonIt(json | error myJson) returns json {
    if (myJson is json) {
       return myJson;
    } else {
       return {};
    }
}
```

With the ternary operator

```
function jsonIt(json | error myJson) returns json {
    return (myJson is json) ? myJson :{};
}
```

The `match` statement performs a value switch. i.e., select the block to execute based on the pattern that a value matches

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a structured match pattern as indicated at => https://www.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/error-match-statement.html